# MAC OUI file missing many manufacturers

Tags: networking, tcp, mac-address, arp

I have a database with many MAC addresses and I have programmed a C code that downloads the oui file from standards-oui.ieee.org, parses it to generate a more useful file for my needs and updates the database with the manufacturer of each MAC.

When I don't find a match in the oui file I set the manufacturer to "Unknown", and now I see that there are a lot of "Unknowns" in the DB!

How can this be possible? ieee should have the OUIs of ALL manufacturer, and it is not very probable that all that MACs with "Unknown" (hundreds) has been spoofed.

I found the wireshark oui file but it doesn't have those manufacturers neither.

Is there a more completed/updated oui source? am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> am I missing something?

Yes, this is a reality where no one gets sanctioned for not using an officially assigned vendor MAC range. So a solid lot of people build ethernet devices which don't.